# How to detect objects real-time with YOLO on RTMP and on Video?

Tags: rtmp, yolo

I have tried to use YOLO with video and RTMP to detect Object in real-time.
I used this:https://github.com/MarcoBay/darknet-rtmp and https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet
But,
The first problem:
when I use this command line, it doesn't work at all as followings.

```
darknet.exe detector demo cfg/coco.data yolocards.cfg yolocards_4000.weights test.mp4 -i 0 -out_filename res.avi
```

...

```
video file: test.mp4
     Video-stream stoped!
    Stream closed.
     Video-stream stoped!
    Stream closed.
```

why this error occurs? 
And the second problem:
I want to use YOLO with RTMP.
How to perform this problem?